# Regular Expression - Negation String + OR

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to match string that are not **11111** OR **22222** (EXACT)

```
<?php
$string = 'STRING'
$pattern = '#PATTER#' // what I have to find
echo preg_match($pattern, $string) ? 'match' : 'no match';
```

Cases:

> $string = '33333';// match
>
> $string = '222222';// match
>
> $string = '11111';// no match
>
> $string = '22222';// no match

I tried many patters that I google and none of them work.

**NOTE**: It has to be pure **REGEX** and **NOT** negating the function **preg_match**

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/JwSjLV

Comment: @JaredFarrish works. Can you please post your answer so I can mark it as the correct answer. I also found this pattern works too: `^(?!.*(3836079|22222)).*$`

Comment: Why do you even use a regex? Just check for one of the two strings using string comparison...

Comment: I don't know if this is important for you, but both mine and your regex will match any string that *starts* with one of the matches. See: http://codepad.viper-7.com/zM4Uyf and http://codepad.viper-7.com/WcQfBR

Comment: :-S I just tested that and yes that is important. So you right my pattern and yours don't work exactly as I need have to be exactly 11111 or 22222. Thank you for point it out.

Comment: @CodeZombie this is a 3rd party program that you set a rule (regular expression) and it will load only records that follow that rule. This is for an ETL program. The code above is just a probe of concept.

Comment: *I tried many patters that I google and none of them work.* - hard to believe...

Comment: @dognose skeptical person. Good for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
 ^(?!11111$|22222$).*
```

test: https://regex101.com/r/wU7yO0/1

Comment: That's clever! And way shorter than my proposed answer.

Comment: easier to understand, if written as `^(?!11111$)(?!22222$).*`: *any* character, neither preceded by 11111 nor 22222.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
^(|.|..|...|....|(?!11111|22222).....|......+)$
```

The basic idea is: All strings of length 0-4 and 6+ are fine. The string of length 5 must not be 11111 or 22222.

Edit: And to compress the length a bit (but make it less readable IMO):

```
^(.{0,4}|(?!11111|22222).{5}|.{6}.*)$
```